# Katalon recorder PHPUnit formatter

Tags: katalon-recorder

I was trying to add a plugin to Katalon recorder (PHPUnit formatter) https://bitbucket.org/inventis/phpunit-formatter-katalon-recorder/src/master/

I followed the instruction in here https://github.com/katalon-studio/katalon-recorder

But everytime I edit `panel\index.html` and add the `php-webdriver-phpunit.js` to `panel\js\katalon\newformatters` Katalon recorder keeps on breaking

Has anyway tried installing PHPUnit formatter in Katalon? or can recommend a plugin that would export PHP code from Katalon recorder?

Answer (score 3):

Got it, for anyone wondering how to add the plugin `PHPUnit formatter` to Katalon recorder

After I downloaded the files from https://bitbucket.org/inventis/phpunit-formatter-katalon-recorder/src/master/ I went to `chrome://extensions` in Google Chrome and click on load unpack button

[image]

Then just select the root directory of the file of PHPUnit formatter

And that's it we can now export using PHP

[image]